# ValidateIssuer option in OpenID connect authentication

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

We are using OIDC library and for now we allow only MSA account login. So we have configured parameters `ValidateIssuer = true` and `Validissuers = https://login.microsoftonline.com/..”`  However, we now need to onboard other AAD tenants (for example : abc@dell.com) to our application so we decided to set `ValidateIssuer = false`.

Since my application is already backed up by custom authorization, I am finding it difficult to understand the purpose of this flag altogether. **Basically my question is under what circumstances one would not like to set this flag to false ? And what risk one might ran into if set to false ?**

I looked at AAD docs published [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-aspnet-webapp#configure-sign-in-options) and still not able to find convincing response from the comments over sample code snippet :

```
        // ValidateIssuer set to false to allow work accounts from any organization to sign in to your application
        // To only allow users from a single organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and 'tenant' setting in web.config to the tenant name or Id (example: contoso.onmicrosoft.com)
        // To allow users from only a list of specific organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and use ValidIssuers parameter
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false
        },
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As the other answer already mentioned, if you leave `ValidateIssuer = false`, then OIDC middleware will not try to validate the issuer tenant and it would effectively mean that your application is open for anyone with a user in Azure AD.

**Some suggestions on tackling multi-tenant case**

1. If you know the list of valid issuers ahead of time, make use of a list of issuers in `TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuers`.
   Example:

   ```
     ValidIssuers = new List<string>()
     {
         "https://sts.windows.net/6d9c0c36-c30e-442b-b60a-ca22d8994d14/",
         "https://sts.windows.net/f69b5f46-9a0d-4a5c-9e25-54e42bbbd4c3/",
         "https://sts.windows.net/fb674642-8965-493d-beee-2703caa74f9a/"
     }
   ```
2. If valid issuers for your application are dynamic or if you want to write some logic to gather that list, you can write an implementation for `TokenValidationParameters.IssuerValidator` which has your custom logic. You just need to set a delegate that will be used to validate the issuer.

   ```
       TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
       {            
           ValidateIssuer = true,

           // Set this to a delegate and write your own custom implementation there. See code sample URL ahead for more details.
           IssuerValidator = AadIssuerValidator.ValidateAadIssuer
       };
   ```
3. If neither case makes sense, and your validation logic is unrelated to the tenant to which caller belongs, set `TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer` to false, but make sure you add your custom logic at the end for example in `SecurityTokenValidated` notifications.

**Sample Code**

[Build a multi-tenant SaaS web application using Azure AD & OpenID Connect](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect)

Look closely at these files in this sample:

- [App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs)
- [Utils/AadIssuerValidator.cs](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/Utils/AadIssuerValidator.cs)

Answer (score 1):

This flag allows the OpenID Connect authentication handler to make sure the person who logs in to your application comes from a known AAD tenant. If you set it to `false`, this validation doesn't happen. What it effectively means is that anyone accessing your application and logging in successfully when being redirected to AAD will be allowed in your application.

In summary, I'd say the only two circumstances you want to set this flag to `false` are if:

- you don't know in advance which tenants can connect to your application; or
- you want to allow people from every single AAD tenant to connect to your application.

Also, I'd be curious to know what you mean by "the application is already backed up by custom authorization".

Cheers

Comment: thanks Mickaël !! I think the base of my question is - is there any security risk by setting it to false. If no, then I still don't understand why I will like to make it explicitly true. Can there be any security risk ? I mentioned _the application is already backed up by custom authorization_ as I was guessing hard the significance of this flag from security perspective and felt if my application already has custom authorization post AAD authentication then still not any tenant can simply access my application.

Comment: Well the risk is that someone from a tenant that you're not supposed to allow to log in can log in. I know you say you have some logic to make sure you don't allow any tenant to access the app. My opinion is that when it comes to security, I'd rather use what's built-in than roll my own. Setting it to `true` and adding the authorized tenants to the `ValidIssuers` property is a built-in mechanism to have control over which tenants can log in.