# Validating Issuer Using issuer 2 or Issuer 1?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to follow the example validation code in
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-manual-jwt-validation/ which states to use Issuer 1.

(REALLY the code in https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-manual-jwt-validation/blob/master/TodoListService-ManualJwt/Global.asax.cs#L136)

- I fetch the issuer/signing keys from:
  `https://login.microsoftonline.com/efa3038a-575b-42ea-8ba1-483cf7f0bdb6/.well-known/openid-configuration`

  - getting issuer:
    `"issuer":"https://sts.windows.net/efa3038a-575b-42ea-8ba1-483cf7f0bdb6/"`
- I fetched my AUTH token with:
  `https://login.microsoftonline.com/efa3038a-575b-42ea-8ba1-483cf7f0bdb6/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=463f8472-dff3-40d0-8ec5-da2d9ba9c348&response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost:30662&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=fragment&state=12345&nonce=678910`

  - which produces a valid token: `eyJ0eX...De0GVw`
  - which decodes (`via var jwt = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JsonWebToken(authorizationHeader.Substring(kBearer_.Length))`) to:
    ....

    `Issuer: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/efa3038a-575b-42ea-8ba1-483cf7f0bdb6/v2.0"`

I then attempt to validate using:

```
TokenValidationParameters validationParams = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    // We accept both the App Id URI and the AppId of this service application
    ValidAudiences = new[] { kADConfiguration_.Audience, kADConfiguration_.ClientId },

    // Supports both the Azure AD V1 and V2 endpoint
    ValidIssuers = new[] { _issuer, $"{_issuer}/v2.0" },
    ValidateIssuer = true,  // set to false and works, set to true it fails

    IssuerSigningKeys = validationInfo.Item2
};
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken v;
System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal answer = handler.ValidateToken(authorizationHeader.Substring(kBearer_.Length), validationParams, out v);
```

I can see that the issuer in the token differs (just the hostname part) from the issuer in the `https://login.microsoftonline.com/efa3038a-575b-42ea-8ba1-483cf7f0bdb6/.well-known/openid-configuration`

But I cannot tell why, or what I'm doing wrong.

I haven't yet found any useful documentation on what parameters to pass to the validation process (for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt.jwtsecuritytokenhandler.validatetoken?view=azure-dotnet just says "validationParameters Contains validation parameters", and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.tokenvalidationparameters.validissuers?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_IdentityModel_Tokens_TokenValidationParameters_ValidIssuers which says "contains valid issuers that will be used to check against the token's issuer."

Comment: note - I found that changing the logic from that sample call to ValidIssues to also include the authority works:   ValidIssuers = new[] {
                            validationInfo.Item1,
                            $"{validationInfo.Item1}/v2.0",
                            kAuthority_,
                            $"{kAuthority_}/v2.0",
                        },

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sample you're currently looking at is a little old and explaining with Azure AD v1.0 endpoint as reference. The issuer value you are seeing in token is correct, because you have acquired that token from Azure AD v2.0 endpoint. The OpenID discovery document URL you're using to find the valid issuer is not correct. More explanation in further sections.

I should also briefly mention that in most cases, explicitly validating the token manually like the [sample you're following](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-manual-jwt-validation/) explains is a bit of heavy lifting which isn't really needed. I don't want to stray off from your orginal question hence I'm just keeping some pointers on this part at the end of my answer, but do take a look to see if it makes sense for your case.

**More details on Access Tokens acquired from Azure AD v1.0 and v2.0 endpoints**

Please look at this Microsoft Documentation - [Access Tokens Reference - Sample Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#sample-tokens)

- [Sample v2.0 Token - Decoded at jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/#access_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Imk2bEdrM0ZaenhSY1ViMkMzbkVRN3N5SEpsWSJ9.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.pj4N-w_3Us9DrBLfpCt) -

  Notice this one has issuer format

  ```
  https://login.microsoftonline.com/<Azure AD Tenant GUID>/v2.0
  ```
- [Sample v1.0 Token - Decoded at jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/#access_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Imk2bEdrM0ZaenhSY1ViMkMzbkVRN3N5SEpsWSIsImtpZCI6Imk2bEdrM0ZaenhSY1ViMkMzbkVRN3N5SEpsWSJ9.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.D3H6pMUtQnoJAGq6AHd) -

  Notice this one has issuer format

  ```
   https://sts.windows.net/<Azure AD Tenant GUID>/
  ```

**OpenID Discovery Document URL for your tenant**

For openid configuration you should be looking at Azure AD v2.0 endpoint, and you will see the correct issuer value there. Specifically for your tenant (as shared in question) correct URL to use will be

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/efa3038a-575b-42ea-8ba1-483cf7f0bdb6/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

The value for OpenID Discovery document that you're currently looking at, is only applicable for tokens acquired from v1.0 endpoint.

**How to find the correct OpenID Discovery Document URL from Azure Portal**

For v2.0 Endpoint, go the preview experience, as shown below. Azure Portal > Azure Active Directory > App Registrations (Preview) > Endpoints

[image]

For v1.0 Endpoint, go to old experience (about to go away). Azure Portal > Azure Active Directory > App Registrations > Endpoints

[image]

---

Like I said initially, for most applications manual token validation is generally not needed.

In case of single tenant applications, generally you just keep ValidateIssuer = true`for the`TokenValidationParameters`

In case of Multi-Tenant applications, there can be a few cases..

- If you know your issuers before hand, you can still set `ValidateIssuer=True` and set the list of ValidIssuers.. `ValidIssuers = new List<string>()...`
- If valid issuers for your application are dynamic or if you want to write some logic to gather that list, you can write an implementation for TokenValidationParameters.IssuerValidator which has your custom logic. You just need to set a delegate that will be used to validate the issuer.
- In other cases, where you still want to write your own custom logic, then explicit validation like the sample you're following makes sense.

Please see a [related SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55767757/validateissuer-option-in-openid-connect-authentication/55771401#55771401) here.

Comment: "a little old" - ??? - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-manual-jwt-validation/ was last updated April 4, 2019 ;-). AND - the second paragraph is "This newer sample takes advantage of the Microsoft identity platform (formerly Azure AD v2.0)."

Comment: And thanks about https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#sample-tokens - I've read it before, but I've now re-read it in light of your suggestions above, and it does make it clear a better way to get the signing keys (well, not better, but newer and different). HOWEVER  it says nothing about (my currently only problem) - which is the issuer. DO I NEED TO VALIDATE the issuer? And if so - how do I properly construct the list of valid issuers?

Comment: I understand the first page says that.. but it seems to be a mistake.. because when you click on `Browse on GitHub` button, the actual code that it's taking you to, is .NET 4.5 based old sample.. which clearly says it uses AAD V1 .. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-manual-jwt-validation

Comment: OK - nevermind. Maybe I do see. When I look at https://login.microsoftonline.com/efa3038a-575b-42ea-8ba1-483cf7f0bdb6/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration - I see the CORRECT issuer. Perhaps that was your point. If so - thank you!

Comment: Just double checking - you are saying the v1 support is old (and maybe going away soon) and I should use the v2 approach, which is what you outlined above - https://login.microsoftonline.com/efa3038a-575b-42ea-8ba1-483cf7f0bdb6/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration and get issuer and signing keys from there. If so - sb pretty easy. Thx.

Comment: **1)** Since token you're trying to validate is issued by v2.0 endpoint, yes you should make use of v2.0 OpenID Discovery document as I say in my answer **2)** Where I mention about to go away soon, it's the Portal experience.. you should see that warning.. here is a screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/yv6wm.png **3)** To understand the differences and general guidance on v1.0 versus v2.0 look here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison **4)** v2.0 would be suggested for developing new apps but be sure to review comparison for your case

Comment: This info was very helpful in tracking down my issue. I wanted to add a tip to that may help others.

In my scenario, I discovered that the app registration (May 2023) changed which token version was generate based on the `Supported account types` setting.

If I chose `Single tenant`, I received V1 tokens.  In my case, someone incorrectly picked `Accounts in any identity provider or organization directory` and this caused v2 tokens to be produced.

I'm guessing that the different settings have different claim requirements that are tied to the token version.

Answer (score 1):

Though the above marked answer was helpful, it was not directly fully an answer. In case anyone has this trouble, here is a snippet of code which can be used to address the above:

...

```
private static AppSettings.ADConfiguration kADConfiguration_ = AppSettings.PeekObj<AppSettings.AuthorizationConfiguration>(AppSettings.kFieldname_Authorization).ADConfiguration;

private static string kAuthority_ = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, kADConfiguration_.AADInstance, kADConfiguration_.Tenant);

private static string _issuer = string.Empty;
private static ICollection<SecurityKey> _signingKeys = null;
private static DateTime _stsMetadataRetrievalTime = DateTime.MinValue;

private static Tuple<string, ICollection<SecurityKey>> AssureSigningKeysAndIssuerUpToDate_()
{
    /*
     *  This logic is based on https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-manual-jwt-validation/blob/master/TodoListService-ManualJwt/Global.asax.cs#L136 ,
     *     as amended in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840510/validating-the-issuer-token-has-issuer-https-login-microsoftonline-com-xv2-0
     */

    // The issuer and signingKeys are cached for 24 hours. They are updated if any of the conditions in the if condition is true.
    if (DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(_stsMetadataRetrievalTime).TotalHours > 24
    || string.IsNullOrEmpty(_issuer)
    || _signingKeys == null)
    {
        // Get tenant information that's used to validate incoming jwt tokens
        string stsDiscoveryEndpoint = $"{kAuthority_}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration";
        var configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(stsDiscoveryEndpoint, new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
        OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = null;
        Task.Run(async () => config = await configManager.GetConfigurationAsync()).Wait();
        _issuer = config.Issuer;
        _signingKeys = config.SigningKeys;
        _stsMetadataRetrievalTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
    return new Tuple<string, ICollection<SecurityKey>>(_issuer, _signingKeys);
}
```

...

```
public String GetUserFromAuthHeader(String authorizationHeader)
{
    const String kBearer_ = "Bearer ";
    if (authorizationHeader.StartsWith(kBearer_))
    {
        System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        Tuple<string, ICollection<SecurityKey>> issuerAndSigningKeys = AssureSigningKeysAndIssuerUpToDate_();
        TokenValidationParameters validationParams = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            // We accept both the App Id URI and the AppId of this service application
            ValidAudiences = new[] { kADConfiguration_.Audience, kADConfiguration_.ClientId },
            ValidIssuers = new[] { issuerAndSigningKeys.Item1, $"{issuerAndSigningKeys.Item1}/v2.0" },
            IssuerSigningKeys = issuerAndSigningKeys.Item2
        };

        SecurityToken v;
        System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal answer = handler.ValidateToken(authorizationHeader.Substring(kBearer_.Length), validationParams, out v);

        //DEBUG - var jwt = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JsonWebToken(authorizationHeader.Substring(kBearer_.Length));
        var claims = answer.Claims;
        foreach (System.Security.Claims.Claim c in claims)
        {
            if (c.Type == "preferred_username")
            {
                return c.Value;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```